# Kotlin - List within a List filtering

Tags: list, lambda, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have those data classes:

```
data class RouteType(

            @SerializedName("type")
            val type: String,

            @SerializedName("items")
            val items: List<RouteItem>)


data class RouteItem(

            @SerializedName("id")
            val id: String,

            @SerializedName("route")
            private val route: List<DoubleArray>)
```

I want to filter list of RouteType by type and filter list of RouteItem in it by id.

My code now:

```
// val filter: HashMap<String, List<String>>

val result = routeTypes  // List<RouteType>
                .filter { it.type in filter.keys }
                .map {
                    routeType -> routeType.items.filter { it.id in filter[routeType.type]!! }
                }
```

How to make `.map` return list with filtered list in it? Or maybe there's another way?

### EDIT

Thanks, but `flatmap` not exactly what I need, I think. `flatmap` returns nested list(`List<RouteItem>`), but I want `List<RouteType>`.

I got it by this code:

```
val result = routeTypes
                .filter { it.type in filter.keys }
                .map {
                    routeType -> RouteType(
                        routeType.type,
                        routeType.items.filter { it.id in filter[routeType.type]!! })
                }
```

Is there another way to get it?

Comment: Is [flatMap()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since your data is immutable (that's a good thing) you need to copy it while filtering. Use `copy` to make it more extensible:

```
val result = routeTypes
        .filter { it.type in filter.keys }
        .map { it.copy(items = it.items.filter { it.id in filter[routeType.type]!! }) }
```

Comment: Welcome! Not sure about using `it` everywhere. For me it is fine here, but feel free to specify names as you see fitted

Comment: what is it here

Comment: "it" in lambdas: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter

Answer (score 3):

You can use flatMap for this, it works as map, but merges all your mapped collections to one:

```
val result = routeTypes  // List<RouteType>
                .filter { it.type in filter.keys }
                .flatMap {
                    routeType -> routeType.items.filter { it.id in filter[routeType.type]!! }
                }
```